# HPE ProLiant ML30 Gen10 fan speed with Agentless Management Service on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hpe, fan

On my MicroServer Gen10, AMSD is able to throttle down the fan speed to 6%, barely noticable. On ML30, it is constantly up between 20-30 %, which is a problem in an office environment.

I am using Ubuntu Server with AMSD successfully working and sending information to iLO.

Has anyone succeeded in throttling down the fan speed on the ML30?

Picture of the iLO amsd:

[amsd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqheb.png)

Picture of the current fan speed in idle. The office temperature is 23C:

[fan speeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYvEx.png)